# Google Map V2 - EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions are optional for Android 6.0 onwards?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission on manifest used by `Google Map V2 API` to load map.

Now, we are building the app to target android SDK to Marshmallow (23). So all the `DANGEROUS` permissions are requested for user permission at runtime. All other permissions are fine, but not sure what we should do with `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.  Even without requesting the user for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` the google map works fine.

On the map Google Map ApiDemo sample, the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is declared on manifest , but comment says `EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions are optional for Android 6.0 onwards.`
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

I don't find any official android document about this. Let me know if you know any information on `EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: They mentioned it in an Android Developer Blog post IIRC.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Thanks . Do we need to target `play service to 8.3 version` to make this optional?

Comment: Probably, though I do not know for certain.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config#specify_android_permissions):

If you're targeting version 8.3 or later of the Google Play services SDK, you no longer need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to use the Google Maps Android API.

If you're targeting earlier versions of the Google Play services SDK, you must request the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Note: If your app is targeting API level 23 (Android 6.0), which requires the use of runtime permissions, you should target version 8.3 or later of the Google Play services SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the detail. Is it mandatory to target `google play service 8.3`? . Since if we target 8.3, it replaces the google wallet to android pay . We can't  support android pay currently , but will happen later. Also , google doesn't allow to mix the play service libraries version numbers. So we have to stay to play service 7.0 for now.